# A user cannot change the password without completing the profile

Tags: templating, user-profile, registration

I have an issue. I have custom fields in the user profile, some of them are required.

I also have a change your password page and a change your email password.

A user can create an account (Without the custom fields).

But when he/she tries to change the password without completing the profile (In the change password page), the password won't be saved as there are some required fields empty.

Comment: Would it be an option to create a custom controller and a few lines of PHP to set the password without the other fields? That's how I usually handle it

Comment: Yes, that's definitely an option, that was actually my solution but I've found that Craft usually has everything I need and that I should try to reinvent the wheel (Learnt that the hard way). So I wanted to make sure first that there's nothing there already.

Comment: You could create a feature request but for now the only time Craft sets the scenario `password` and not `scenario live` (which will validate fields) is during a public registration process or after a user receives a password reset mail.